# WooCommerce add to cart not working

Tags: wordpress, azure, woocommerce

my wordpress site is hosted on windows azure and recently after a WooCommerce and Wordpress update my add to cart button does not add any products to my cart.
It redirects to the cart fine but lways displays 'your cart is currently empty' unless i am logged in as the Admin

i have checked the WooCommerce system status and all appears ok

anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Today, I faced this same issue. I learnt I was running close to the memory limit on my site, so upped it a notch. Also, after de-activating the WP Super Cache, the added products showed up in the cart. However, after few rounds of testing, De-activating the wp super cache and re-activating did not make the problem go away. You may try the above and see if it works for you.

I know this is an old post. If you have already found a solution, please share.

mitmak